# How to add a custom MessageListener to existing message driven channel adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to add a message listener to a my message driven channel adapter (in order to read some headers from messages passing through it).
The [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#jms-message-driven-channel-adapter) sounds like I have to reference a messageListenerContainer and add a messageListener to it. In order to get my hand on the message, I add my own messageListener.

The relevant part of the (xml) implementation looks like this:

```
    <bean id="myOwnMessageListener" class="com.my.project.MyOwnMessageListener">
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="myListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" >
<!--        <bean id="myListener" class="com.my.project.MyOwnMessageListenerContainer" > -->
        <property name="messageListener" ref="myOwnMessageListener"/>
        <property name="autoStartup" value="false" />
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactoryCaching" />
        <property name="destination" ref="jmsQueue" />
        <property name="maxMessagesPerTask" value="1" />
        <property name="receiveTimeout" value="1" />
        <property name="backOff" ref="fixedBackOff" />
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${INBOUND_CONSUMERS}"/>
        <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="${INBOUND_MAX_CONSUMERS}"/>
        <property name="errorHandler" ref="connectionJmsError"/>   
        <property name="exceptionListener" ref="connectionJmsException"/>           
    </bean>
    
    <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn" container="myListener" channel="channelJms_Jms" error-channel="myErrorChannel"/>
```

And from the MyOwnMessageListener :

```
public class MyOwnMessageListener implements javax.jms.MessageListener {


    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyOwnMessageListener.class);
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        LOG.debug("onMessage called...")

    }
}
```

My pb is that the MessageListener is never used : neither the constructor nor the message handler are called.

I have tried implementing my own MessageListenerContainer as well, but its constructor is not called either.

And when I used debug mode (under Eclipse), I see a thread called "MyListener" whose name shows a number increasing very fastly : this looks like stg is not well in my configuration....
But so far, I can't understand what's wrong here.

There is a lot of information in the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#jms-message-driven-channel-adapter), but since I am quite newbie to both spring-integration and Message Oriented Middlewares, I may miss obvious solutions from there.
So if anyone may point out my mistake here... it would help a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use an `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` for that listener container its own `SessionAwareMessageListener` becomes a listener inside of that container internally by the Framework. That means that your own `myOwnMessageListener` is overridden and the real listener work happens, it is really a fact that it is not called since everything is delegated to the `ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener` via `JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint`.

You should have access to the desired headers in the service activator subscribed to that `channelJms_Jms` where the mentioned `ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener` is publishing a message from JMS prepared for you.

The point is: if you use already Spring Integration, then you have to rely on its patterns and components to deal with messages. Otherwise you need to back off and use plain Spring JMS with its container and listener API directly.

Comment: This is very clear, thanks for your answer. I will read further for a better understanding of the pattern, in order to avoir such pitfall. And I will look into my channel and activators since I now understand I am looking the wrong way!